# How to create the folder structure from info defined in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, directory-structure

I created a dataframe that lists all files and folders in my Google Drive. I've been able to filter it down to only the folders. I now want to recreate that same folder structure on my local computer.

So the dataframe has a unique folder id # for each folder, the name of the folder, and the id of each folder's parent folder, like this:

[image: dataframe info]

I suspect I'll need to use Python os to recursively create this structure. So far I've been able to create the first level of folders (in the top level) by specifying the parent id #:

```
parent_directory = 'test_dirs'
for row in df.itertuples():
    if getattr(row, 'parent_folder_id#') == '0':
        directory = getattr(row, 'folder_name')
        path = os.path.join(parent_directory, directory)
        os.mkdir(path)
    else:
        pass
```

But how would I make this recursive to be able to create all of the nested folders at once?

**Edit**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72166494/14343826 helped me think about creating a dictionary from the dataframe where the keys are folder paths (made from the folder names) and the values are folder ids, like:

```
lookup = {'A': '1', 'B': '2', ..., 'A/A names/A john smith': '7'}
```

So it basically goes through each row of the dataframe, checks for the row's parent folder id in the dictionary, when it finds the parent folder it adds that name in front of the current folder's name and adds a new entry to the dictionary for that. That solves the nested folder creation.

Code:

```
lookup = {'Root': '0'}

for row in df.itertuples():
    folder_id = getattr(row, 'folder_id#')
    folder_name = getattr(row, 'folder_name')
    folder_parents = getattr(row, 'parent_folder_id#')
    path = list(lookup.keys())[list(lookup.values()).index(folder_parents)] + '/' + folder_name
    lookup[path] = folder_id
    os.makedirs(path)
```

Comment: To clarify, `A john smith` parent folder id # is 5, which means it is nested under `A names`, and the path would be `A/names/john smith`. Is that correct? Also, is the dataframe column sorted such that as you go down the column, the succeeding folders are nested under some folder from a previous row? For example, there won't be a top-level folder folder_id=10 folder_name=X somewhere down the column?

Comment: It doesn't have to be recursive.  Just remember in a list what the full path for that row is.  Then when you process #7, you can look up #5, add `"A john smith"`, and do the mkdir.

Comment: @GinoMempin Yes that example path is correct. I was just including arbitrary names but wanted to show that some folders contain no folders and that there are various levels of subfolders. And yes to your second question as well. The folders are sorted so that all folders are nested under a folder above them (the only exception being the first set of folders that are all in the root folder that does not appear in the dataframe... but which I could easily add).

Comment: @TimRoberts So store every row's folder name in a list, and join the names with slashes, and mkdir everything in the list? I just suppose I'm wondering mechanically how to do that -- is it possible with .itertuples() and if statements to see if one row's "parent" is == a previous row's "folder_id"? Slowly teaching myself Python, so I really don't know.

Comment: You can do the `mkdir`s on the fly, but remember what it is you made so you can prepend it when the if# comes up again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remember where you've been as you make them:

```
lookup = {'0': 'test_dirs' }
for row in df.itertuples():
    parent = getattr(row, 'parent_folder_id#')
    path = os.path.join( parent, directory )
    os.mkdir(path)
    lookup[getattr(row, 'folder_id#')] = path
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It inspired me to make a dictionary from the dataframe where the keys were the folder paths and the values were the folder ids. After I had that, it was a simple for loop through the dictionary keys with an `os.makedirs(key)` to build out the folders.